# use checkbox to send textview value to another activity using image button onclick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

i am making a program, in which i am using 3 checkboxes for the item variations along with 3 textviews for their prices, now i want to know, whenever user will click on checkbox1 then price appears in textview1 send to next activity, like in second activity you have selected : checkbox1 $2.00,i want to do this using image button for add to order, please write some brief code how is it possible for me. Here i am placing main.xml code:-

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/regular"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/var1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="$2.00"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/var2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cost"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/var1"
        android:text="Small" />
           <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/var2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/var1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="$1.00"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/var3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cost"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/var2"
        android:text="Large" />
           <TextView
        android:id="@+id/large"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/var3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/var2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="$3.00"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="15dip" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_order"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add_order" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to your ImageButton. Now if the onClick method is called retrieve the state of the checkboxes and determine the price of the item.

This price can now  be added to the Intent that you use to start the next Activity. 
Use the setExtra and getExtra Methods of the Intent class as explained in this [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: Janusz i appreciate, could you please write some code if checkbox1 is checked then value of textview1 send to textview2 that's it, because i have read the link and now i am able to send value to another activity.....thanks

Comment: do you want to send values to another activity?

Comment: Bro,after read above link now i can send value to another activity, but i want whenever user will check on checkbox then value of one textview send to another textview in same activity using image button...please write some code

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageButton btn;
private TextView txtSmall, txtMed,txtLarge;
private CheckBox chkSmall, chkLarge;
private String strSmall, strLarge;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Checkbox Declaration
    chkSmall = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.var2);
    chkLarge = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.var3);

    //TextView Declaration
    txtSmall = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.small);
    txtLarge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.large);

    //ImageButton
    btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_order);

    //RESET VALUES
    strSmall = txtSmall.getText().toString();
    strLarge = txtLarge.getText().toString();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(chkSmall.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMALL CHECKBOX SELECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtLarge.setText(txtSmall.getText().toString());
            }
            else if(chkLarge.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LARGE CHECKBOX SELECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtSmall.setText(txtLarge.getText().toString());
            }
           else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RESET Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtSmall.setText(strSmall);
                txtLarge.setText(strLarge);
            }

        }

    });


}
```

Here Your XML code set to layout.